# How to apply transparency to text in GTK2 widgets?

Tags: c, gtk2, xfce

I've been playing around with Xfce 4.12, which uses GTK2, and I would like to make taskbar buttons to have semi-transparent text when their respective windows are minimized. Here's the original code:

```
xfce_tasklist_button_name_changed (WnckWindow *window, XfceTasklistChild *child)
{
    const gchar *name;
    gchar *label = NULL;

    panel_return_if_fail (window == NULL || child->window == window);
    panel_return_if_fail (WNCK_IS_WINDOW (child->window));
    panel_return_if_fail (XFCE_IS_TASKLIST (child->tasklist));

    name = wnck_window_get_name (child->window);
    gtk_widget_set_tooltip_text (GTK_WIDGET (child->button), name);

    if (!child->tasklist->only_minimized && wnck_window_is_minimized (child->window))
        name = label = g_strdup_printf ("[%s]", name);
    else if (wnck_window_is_shaded (child->window))
        name = label = g_strdup_printf ("=%s=", name);

    gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL (child->label), name);

    g_free (label);

    if (window != NULL)
        xfce_tasklist_sort (child->tasklist);
}
```

I tried countless things, but I failed to find a way to apply alpha to the text in the widget.

Interesting to notice that the icons next to the text have alpha using pixbuf, which I guess doesn't work for text in widgets:

```
  XfceTasklist *tasklist = child->tasklist;
  GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = wnck_window_get_icon (window);
  GdkPixbuf *lucent = lucent = exo_gdk_pixbuf_lucent (pixbuf, tasklist->minimized_icon_lucency);

  if (G_UNLIKELY (lucent != NULL))
      pixbuf = lucent;
  
  xfce_panel_image_set_from_pixbuf (XFCE_PANEL_IMAGE (child->icon), pixbuf);
```

Comment: Why not Xfce 4.14+ and Gtk 3?

Comment: Because since 4.14 Xfce got slower, not bringing any benefits to my use cases.